# Windows XP - Websites don't display correctly and other problems

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, firefox

Windows XP

Every single page in Firefox displays incorrectly. All color and formatting is gone. 
Here's how it should not look like, but how it looks in my Firefox:

[image]

In Chrome it displays correctly.

However, we now have connection issues.

Firefox displays stackoverflow login page with the crappy formatting issues, but it works.

Chrome, gives me invalid server certificate on a red page, and https has a red slash through it in the omnibox and it doesn't let me access the page.

Help needed ASAP!!

Comment: I can't answer this but I am surprised you are having issues with it. I don't use Firefox anymore and have started using Chrome. However, I have never had any issues with it so I am unsure what the problem may be.

Comment: @L.B. I know, right? This also shows up in Windows Security Center as well, and when I install flash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your Firefox colour options:

Goto Menu / Tools / Options/ Content/ Colours.

Select "Allow pages to choose their own colours, instead of my selections above"

Press OK

Press OK again.

[image]

Comment: thats been checked this whole time. also can you help me with the second part of my question, the https?

Comment: Then maybe you have an extension causing the problem. What happens when you start firefox in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode)?